# How can I see the products per each category with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

this is my schema for storing products using mongoose as below.

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const mongoosePaginate = require("mongoose-paginate-v2");

    const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      category: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Category",
      },
      productImage: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      description: {
        type: String,
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date(),
      },
      deletedAt: {
        type: Date,
      },
    });

    productSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);

    const productModel = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema, "Product");

    module.exports = productModel;
```

and this how I have the schema for storing categories that products are related to

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");

    const categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
      _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      product: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Product" },
    });

    const categoryModel = mongoose.model("Category", categorySchema, "Category");

    module.exports = categoryModel;
```

What I don´t know is how to populate my controller.

```
 getAll: async (req, res) => {
    const limitPage = parseInt(req.query.limit, 10) || 10;
    const pageChange = parseInt(req.query.page, 10) || 1;
    Product.paginate({}, { limit: limitPage, page: pageChange })
      .then((result) => {
        return res.status(200).json({
          message: "GET request to all getAllProducts",
          dataCount: result.length,
          result: result,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
          error: err,
        });
      });
  },
```

Please help, I don´t understand why it not being populated and how to see the categories displayed with the categorie they belong to.

Comment: You got all your products, so what is it do you want to achieve? Did you try using `populate`?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably include `populate` in your query like so:

```
...
Product.paginate({}, { limit: limitPage, page: pageChange }).populate('category')
...
```

Note: Are you sure you want to have a 1-1 relation between products and categories. Because this is what you achieve if you set the relation like you did on both schemas. If yes, you should find a way to ensure that this 1-1 relation is enforced each time you save or update objects.